# SQL Server : Extracting Everything Before a Certain Character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this:

```
21654-8012
1234-127834
12345-1222
```

I want to extract this:

```
21654
1234
12345
```

Basically, everything before the hyphen, `-`  character. Does anyone have any suggestions on where to start?

Comment: Use [LEFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I tried playing with Left, but I didn't know there was a CHARINDEX function. Will try that

Comment: bingo, it worked. You should have posted this as the answer so I could give you credit :p

Comment: No biggie. I don't care much about points. Glad you got it solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `left` WITH `charindex()` :

```
select t.col, left(col, charindex('-', col)-1)
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CHARINDEX function

```
   DECLARE @text VARCHAR(20)
   SET @text = '123456-0000'
   SELECT SUBSTRING(@text, 0, CHARINDEX('-', @text))
```

Instead of @text, you can use your field name

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING(YOUR_COLUMN_NAME, 0, CHARINDEX('-', YOUR_COLUMN_NAME)) FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME
```